# Power BI Line Chart to show weekinmonth

Tags: powerbi

I want to show weekinmonth trend line for my data ( I have data from August - December) and I further drill it down to weekinmonth as per below illustration.

[image]

[image]

However, for December month, there were only 2 weeks of data. But the trend line shows 5 weeks. It can be seen on the right handside table that there are only 2 weeks in December month. How can I fix this in order for the line chart to show only 2 weeks data as per the dataset instead of 5.

[image]

[image]

Could someone please help me with this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I do not think you are drilling down to december but you drull down in weeks. Check if your drill down is total/avg of all weeks in all months.